# Synchronous request with mysql query in nodejs

Tags: node.js, express, nodes

I am working on node.js with express framework and I am trying to call multiple mysql queries and each query depend upon the previous queries.
How can be execute query in synchronously.

```
function f1(id, cb) {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM s1 where process_id=" +id;

    connection.query(
        $sql, 
        function (err, result) {         
            if (err) {
                cb(err, null);
            } else {
                var str = '';

                if (result.length > 0) {
                    for(val in result) {
                        $sql = "SELECT attribute_name FROM s2 where id=" + result[val].id;

                        connection.query(
                            $sql, 
                            function (err, attrresult) {         
                                if (err) {
                                    cb(err, null);
                                } else {
                                    if (result.length > 0) {
                                        str  +=  attrresult[0].attribute_name;
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        );              
                    }
                }

                cb('', str);
            }                
        }
    );
}

router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {  
    f1('27', function (err,respose) {
        console.log(respose);
    });
});
```

Please suggest. How can we do this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can't really make the synchronous, but you can make then look like sync code by making use of promises and generators.

```
function mySexyMethod() {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        someAsyncethod(params, function (err, data) {
            if (err) {
                return reject(err);
            }

            resolve(data);
        })
    });
}
```

Express router

```
var wrap = require('co-express');

router.verb('some-route', wrap(function* (req, res, next) {

    var val, val2;

    try {
        val = yield mySexyMethod();
        val2 = yield anotherPromiseThatRequiresPreviousVal(val);
    } catch (e) {
        return next(e);
    }
});
```

Even better, look into https://www.npmjs.com/package/bluebird and check if whatever mysql lib you are using can be promisified.

Comment: In your solution `mySexyMethod` and `anotherPromiseThatRequiresPreviousVal` will be executed in parallel. You cannot use the result of the first one in the second one. Moreover, your solution seems to be incomplete because you define your promise but never use it.

Comment: @Gnucki - Nope. It will wait. See that "yield", it makes sure that whatever you got after that waits. I kind of totally use the `mySexyMethod `. Look up generators and promises. You can thank me later.

Comment: Sorry, my bad, I red too fast and didn't see you were using `co-express`. That's an interesting solution.

Answer (score 0):

you can use promise chaining, or async package to handle series execution, step by step
check the below guide for promise chaining
https://coderwall.com/p/ijy61g/promise-chains-with-node-js

for async check the following package
https://github.com/caolan/async

Answer (score 0):

Node I/O is async by definition. I think your problem is the for loop. It loops all the iterations before the matching-per-variable nested query callback. So use some mechanism to achieve the desired flow of execution. You can use promises, there are several good libs(Q,Bluebird,native promises with ES2015...) Also you can use [async.js](https://github.com/caolan/async) wich is easier to deal with it.

The libs are not mandatory but they do the work easier.

Answer (score 0):

As everybody said, [Async.js](https://github.com/caolan/async) is a nice solution to do this kind of thing.

However it could be a little hard to handle at the beginning. If you like to have a little more abstraction, I would suggest you to use a framework like [Danf](https://github.com/gnodi/danf) (build upon Express). This framework abstracts Async.js to handle asynchronicity (execute operations in series, in parallel, ...) in an original and simple way. Take a look at the [overview](https://github.com/gnodi/danf/blob/master/resource/private/doc/overview/index.md) to understand what I mean.